# Comparing two series of measurements

Tags: data-visualization, descriptive-statistics

I measured execution times in environments A-1/2 and B-1/2 for tasks I and II.
I performed these measurements in two different contexts V1 and V2.

[image]

[image]

I have created a third table in which I form absolute difference between the cells of V1 and V2.

[image]

I now want to show that V1 and V2 do not differ much.
Do you have recommendations how I can 1. statistically calculate this and 2. visualize it clearly?

**EDIT 1:**
Ok. I have now tried to perform a Wilcoxon Signed rank test.

The Wilcoxon Signed rank test statistic "Wstat" is 88, which is greater than the critical value "Wkrit" 58. As far as I can remember from my statistics lecture, this therefore says that H0 is true. Is this correct?

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I have now run the Wilcoxon test in R as recommended in the comments. I have converted the times to minutes.

```
library(psych)
t0 <- c(9,8,113,100,20,227,252,115,96,127,106,222,201,412,119,102,245,212,251,423,674)
t10 <- c(8,7,121,114,18,231,243,103,92,134,111,217,208,400,115,95,242,226,238,438,666)

describe(t0)
describe(t10)

wilcox.test(t0,t10,paired=TRUE,exact=FALSE,correct=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
   vars  n  mean     sd median trimmed    mad min max range skew kurtosis    se
X1    1 21 192.1 157.86    127  171.76 140.85   8 674   666 1.37     1.81 34.45
   vars  n   mean     sd median trimmed   mad min max range skew kurtosis    se
X1    1 21 191.76 156.83    134  171.06 136.4   7 666   659 1.34     1.71 34.22

    Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  t0 and t10
V = 121, p-value = 0.8619
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

But why do I get such a high p-value? With p = 0.8619 the null hypothesis is rejected very clearly, isn't it?

Comment: Why not fit a model to the data, with explanatory variables for environment, task and context? Then you can formulate a test for the null hypothesis that there is no context effect. Also, are the times in the table averages of several measurements under the same setting?

Comment: @dipetkov Thanks for the suggestions. I'm just unsure how to fit a model to the data. Do I need three dimensional regression then? As a first attempt, I created a bar chart for each context. Should I formulate a hypothesis test based on these? And no, the data was measured once.

Comment: Without replication, there are limits to how much you can learn (statistically) from the data and so making visualization would be a good place to start. A simple test for the null hypothesis of no difference between the two contexts V1 and V2 may be a paired test on the differences `V1 - V2` (in seconds and without taking the absolute value): Wilcoxon signed-rank test or a permutation test could be appropriate.

Comment: @dipetkov Thanks for your advices. I totally forgot about the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. I have edited the post and performed the test.

Comment: I use R, not Excel. And here is the Wilcoxon signed rank test applied to your data: `diffs <- c(1, 1, -8, -14, 2, -4, 9, 12, 4, -7, -5, 5, -7, -18, 4, 7, -16, -14, 13, -15, 8);
wilcox.test(diffs, correct = FALSE)`. The result is: `V = 91, p-value = 0.394`.

Comment: And we don't say the null hypothesis is true (or accept the null hypothesis). The correct conclusion is that we don't reject the null hypothesis because it's consistent with the data.

Comment: @dipetkov I tried to do the Wilcoxon test in R as you commented with the absolute minutes. However, an even higher P-value than yours signals that the null hypothesis is rejected, although the samples are obviously similar...

Comment: Taking the absolute value of the differences is not correct. It may be worth reading up on the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. (And the word "signed" in the name of the test is a hint.)

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me. I didn't use the absolute differences when performing the Wilcoxon test in R. Please take a look at my second edit. I was trying to replicate your p-value in R by calculating with the paired minute values.

Comment: I'll assume you did the algebra right. However this statement: "With p = 0.8619 the null hypothesis is rejected very clearly, isn't it?" is quite wrong. Please read up on p-values. This result means quite the opposite (as I already mentioned in a previous comment): this p-value means we don't reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Oh, now I understand your comment. Then it's all settled, thanks for your patience and support! Sorry, I am a CS undergraduate and am not familiar with hypothesis testing.

Comment: No need to apologize for having questions. If you'd like to learn more stats, I recommend this  (free online) resource: [Improving Your Statistical Inferences](https://lakens.github.io/statistical_inferences/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with a warning. You performed the experiment only once, ie. took one measurement for each combination of environment, task and context.

This would limit how much you can learn from the data. For example, without replication, it's a challenge to estimate the measurement error at a given setting (because you have just one measurement at each setting). It also means that you couldn't vary the order in which exercises were executed (for the combined setting such as "A-1 + A-2"). In short, you should consider this a preliminary investigation to find direction(s) for future experiments.

With this caveat, you are only interested in whether there is a difference in execution time between the two contexts, V1 and V2.

Since there is exactly one measurement from each context for each combination of task & environment, we will treat these two measurements as paired and test the null hypothesis of no difference between contexts with the Wilcoxon signed rank test. We assume that the pairs are randomly and independently drawn. This is a strong assumption as it requires that the context doesn't interact with either the task or the environment. (More on this later.)

```r
with(
  data,
  wilcox.test(V1, V2, paired = TRUE)
)
#>  Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  V1 and V2
#> V = 91, p-value = 0.4038
#> alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Equivalently, we can look at the difference between the two paired execution times.

```r
with(
  data,
  wilcox.test(V1 - V2)
)
#>  Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  V1 - V2
#> V = 91, p-value = 0.4038
#> alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

*Aside*: You report a difference statistic and p-value because you have a couple of typos: V1 & V2 for Task III, environment B-1 (these times seems to have been swapped?); V2 for Task II, environment A-1 + A-2 + B-1 + B-2. The typos don't make any difference to the conclusion of the test: we don't reject the null hypothesis of no difference between the context.

Next let's look at the second part of your question: how to visualize the data clearly. I came up with this plot which uses colors, shapes and panels to indicate task, environment and context. I decided to split the *environment* into *category*: A, B or A+B and *combination*: 1, 2 or 1+2.

[image]

The plot highlights rather obviously that there is an interaction between *context* and *category*: when category = A, execution times are shorter under the V2 context; when category = B, execution times are shorted in the V1 context. We can also test this formally with a Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test.

```r
with(
  data,
  kruskal.test(V1 - V2, category)
)
#> 
#>  Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 
#> data:  V1 - V2 and category
#> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 10.706, df = 2, p-value = 0.004734
```

Now the null hypothesis of no difference between the two context in the two different environments is rejected. A good next step for your study might be to investigate this hint of an interaction further.

---

R code to reproduce the analysis and the figure:

```r
library("lubridate")
library("tidyverse")

data <-
  tribble(
    ~task, ~environment, ~V1, ~V2,
    "I", "A-1", "00:09", "00:08",
    "I", "A-2", "00:08", "00:07",
    "I", "B-1", "01:53", "02:01",
    "I", "B-2", "01:40", "01:54",
    "I", "A-1+A-2", "00:20", "00:18",
    "I", "B-1+B-2", "03:47", "03:51",
    "I", "A-1+A-2+B-1+B-2", "04:12", "04:03",
    "II", "A-1", "01:55", "01:43",
    "II", "A-2", "01:36", "01:32",
    "II", "B-1", "02:07", "02:14",
    "II", "B-2", "01:46", "01:51",
    "II", "A-1+A-2", "03:42", "03:37",
    "II", "B-1+B-2", "03:21", "03:28",
    "II", "A-1+A-2+B-1+B-2", "06:52", "07:10",
    "III", "A-1", "01:59", "01:55",
    "III", "A-2", "01:42", "01:35",
    "III", "B-1", "04:02", "04:18",
    "III", "B-2", "03:32", "03:46",
    "III", "A-1+A-2", "04:11", "03:58",
    "III", "B-1+B-2", "07:03", "07:18",
    "III", "A-1+A-2+B-1+B-2", "11:14", "11:06"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(V1, V2), ~ period_to_seconds(ms(.))),
    category = case_when(
      environment %in% c("A-1", "A-2", "A-1+A-2") ~ "A",
      environment %in% c("B-1", "B-2", "B-1+B-2") ~ "B",
      environment %in% c("A-1+A-2+B-1+B-2") ~ "A+B"
    ),
    category = factor(category, levels = c("A", "B", "A+B")),
    combination = case_when(
      environment %in% c("A-1", "B-1") ~ "1",
      environment %in% c("A-2", "B-2") ~ "2",
      environment %in% c("A-1+A-2", "B-1+B-2", "A-1+A-2+B-1+B-2") ~ "1+2"
    ),
    combination = factor(combination, levels = c("1", "2", "1+2"))
  )

with(
  data,
  wilcox.test(V1, V2, paired = TRUE)
)
with(
  data,
  wilcox.test(V1 - V2)
)
with(
  data,
  kruskal.test(V1 - V2, category)
)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    c(V1, V2),
    names_to = "context",
    values_to = "time"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(context, time)
  ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(
      group = interaction(task, environment),
      color = task,
      linetype = combination
    ),
    linewidth = 1
  ) +
  facet_grid(
    ~category
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = c(1, 3, 4)
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = "execution time (sec)"
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.margin = margin()
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort to formulate your comments as a detailed answer!